# How do you rig a 3d scanned object?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I downloaded a model to rig (see below)
[image]

but I want it to look more like 
[image]
So that it can be effectively rigged.

Comment: You need to do retopology, and if you want it to be animated think about making it guad based.

Comment: Scanned objects usually come with terrible topology, meaning that they are not optimized for rigging in any way.  Your best bet is to re-topologize with the aim of having correct edge flow and with vertices that help with the correct deformation of the mesh once it has an armature.

Comment: Also, imho that model is not thought (designed) to be animated, likely. So it will be difficult to get a decent deformation from its legs, eg. There's a reason if most models rigging starts (for bipeds) on T position...